# Sequence whose limit is given set

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space with infinite elements. Consider $\{x_n\}$ the sequence of infinite distinct points in $X$. We say this sequence is convergent if there is a $x$ in $X$ such that for each nbd $G$ of $x$ a positive integer $N$ can be found such that $x_n \in G$ for all $n \geq N$. This point $x$ is said to be a limit of the sequence $\{x_n\}$.

If I consider topology $T = \{\, \varnothing, X \, \}$ then any sequence converges every point of the space. This demonstrates that in an arbitrary space limit need not be unique.

If I consider the discrete topology and let $x$ be a point, suppose a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with infinitely many distinct points and consider $G = \{x, x'\}$. Clearly $G$ is an open nbd of $x$. Then it is easy to see that $\{x_n\}$ doesn't converge to $x$ since there are infinitly many distinct $x_n$ s.

However if the space is Hausdorff then we can easily observe that every convergent sequence has unique limit.

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Now my aim is to find a topology in which there is a sequence whose limit points are precisely the set $A$. It is clear that if $A$ is full space and empty then trivial and discrete topologies would work. If $A$ is singleton then Hausdorff space will work. So for a proper subset $A$ of $X$ does there exist topology in which the limit points of a sequence is $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\tau = \{\varnothing,A,X \setminus A,X\}$ and $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of elements in $A$. Observe that for any $x \in A$, $G$ only can be $A$ or $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the two extreme cases that you already know: let

$$\tau=\{X\}\cup\wp(X\setminus A)\,.$$

Let $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in $X$ with infinitely many distinct points. If $x\notin A$, $\{x\}$ is an open nbhd of $x$ that does not contain a tail of $\sigma$, so $\sigma$ does not converge to $x$. If $x\in A$, then $X$ is the only open nbhd of $x$, so $\sigma$ converges to $x$.

In fact, the only sequences in $X$ that do **not** have $A$ as their set of limit points are those that are eventually constant.